# What's the best way to "package" a c application?

Tags: c, build, makefile

Everytime I leave a c application unattended for a while, upgrade my distribution or change some packages the build immediately breaks.

What I would need is a build system that downloads the specific library with a specific version as a .zip and installs it on the machine as part of the build process. Even better would be a local installation into a /lib folder.
But then I also have a few dependencies, like for example the library might need libjpeg-dev for the full featureset.

The build systems I know (make, tup, cmake) dont handle pulling dependencies. I would like something like maven for c, does that exist?

Answer (score 2):

You can have your `Makefile` auto-generate dependencies using the `-M` and related [preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) flags to `gcc`; so your build will be done if external included files have changed.

You might be interested by [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf). It will detect some dependencies but won't pull them. And [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) can help too.

Regarding pulling the dependencies, this is operating system specific and related to the [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager). So it is different on Debian or Ubuntu (using `aptitude` and [`.deb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29) packages) and on Fedora (using `yum` and [`.rpm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) packages)

It looks like you want a universal package manager, and there is none. **Each Linux distribution has its own package management** (and I heard that Window or MacOSX have several or none, depending how you count them).

BTW, **the management of packages is the business of the sysadmin**. He certainly doesn't want that to be fully automatic (because the package manager can detect some conflicts specific to his computer).

And last, you usually should not want a *specific* version of a library; you just care about the [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface). You usually want at least some given version (or later) since that defines the API you care about: if your program uses [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) 3.14 it is very likely to be buildable and run with GTK 3.16 (since their API is compatible).

You could switch to more modern languages, with a better support for [modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) (C and even C++ does not know about them; they might appear in some future version of C++, maybe C++17). For example, [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/) has real first class modules and functors, and also has the [Opam](http://opam.ocamlpro.com/) (Ocaml-specific) package manager.

Comment: I dont understand, how would a gcc preprocessor flag download graphicsmagick from the internet and compile+install it with a specific --options set?

Comment: It won't. But if you did pull them, it would help `make` to recompile the *relevant* code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like bazel can do both: be a build system and a dependency manager

http://bazel.io/docs/external.html